# How to show store view in grid after save

Tags: magento2

[image]
This is my form and after save store view i want to display it in grid am saving id of this

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually i create cuistom form and saving store view in custom table and in custom table saving id and now i want to show this in grid and right now its showin id in grid but i want to show store name

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example in the cms module for cms pages or blocks.
cms_page_listing.xml ui component.

add this inside the `listingToolbar` tag

```
        <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
            <settings>
                <captionValue>0</captionValue>
                <options class="Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options"/>
                <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                <imports>
                    <link name="visible">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </filterSelect>
```

and this inside the columns section

```
    <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Store View</label>
            <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
```